# When running Nuxt generate my Babel does not transpile the "Symbol" type for IE11

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, nuxt.js, generate

I have created a Nuxt.js application and right now I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem with Babel7. I have installed the following babel packages:

```
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.4",
```

And my babel configuration in nuxt-config.js looks like this:

```
babel: {
        presets: [
            ["@babel/preset-env", {
                useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                corejs: '3.1.0',
                targets: {
                    ie: 11,
                    browsers: 'last 2 versions, >1%, not dead'
                }
            }],
        ],
        plugins: [
            ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"],
            ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
                "regenerator": true
            }]
        ]
    },
```

(Obviously this is within the build object). Now if I'm correct, this should transpile the Symbol type, because the "targets" object contains IE11, right? And since useBuiltIns is set to usage it should work.

There's no issue with Nuxt Generate at all. Everything is working correctly and everything is generated as it should be. However when I open IE11 I get the following errors:

[Symbol undefined issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9DJK.png)